# Is there a difference between the Samurai X and Ruroni Kenshin anime?

Tags: anime, rurouni-kenshin

IS there some significant difference between the **Samurai X** version and the  **Rurouni Kenshin** anime of the same manga?

I'm not speaking here of the different "period" adaptations.

*Rurouni Kenshin* is a franchise that started in the mid 90s, and has (to my knowledge) one long anime, a few OVA, and several movie (anime, and live action) versions. Following the progression of the wandering ronin Swordsman, Kenshin Himura, the tale itself runs over 20 odd years, from his time as a warrior in the Bakumatus (pre-Meji era Warring States period) to the time after the Reformation, there are a lot of differences between the two "eras" of the story.

[image]

The 2 year long anime seems to be most often known as **Rurouni Kenshin;** most commonly, the English-language versions of the OVAs, as well as the film, are released as **Samurai X** in North America, although the original name was included on the later DVD and Blu-ray Disc releases.

[image][image]

Art taken from the *Samurai X* series.

[image]

The look of the prequel Bakumatsu OVA

[image]

Art style of the sequel OVA

Differences in art style aside, these stories themselves can be fit into a chronological order, as they are meant to essentially be different time periods of the same tale. However, there seem to be differences in the anime series between its *Rorouni Kenshin* and *Samurai X* versions; for some reason, it was re-dubbed twice, and this seems to have altered some characters (along with their voices) and story elements. Changes I've seen seem to be mostly cosmetic (the main character is known as "Ken-SHI" in one, and "Ken-SHIN" in the other, the voice cast is largely rearranged, and some music is altered).

I never saw the full cut of +RK_ as an anime, though, and it seems like some episodes; plots were taken out. While not quite on the level of **Full Metal Alchemist** and **Full Metal Alchemist: Brotherhood,** (both of which used the exact same voice actors, but somehow told different stories while sticking to basic over all structure), it's been said there are some significant changes.

If there are any, what are the main differences in the adaptations?

If its essentially the same series, why was it redubbed twice?

And was there a manga continuation after the final OVA took place?

Comment: Samurai X is the name attached to the Trust and Betrayal OVAs, and Rurouni Kenshin is the name applied to the original series

Comment: @someoneuseless Nah, my dude. I _think_ it's the same series, but there are **Two different versions.** One of the most notable would be the voice cast; while Kenshi is the same in both, all other principle characters have essentially been changed. Sanosuke Sagara,_ for instance, was voiced by Derek Stephen Prince in **Samurai X** and by Lex Lang in **Rorouni.**

Comment: It's the name attached to the North American release. It was only used used on the OVA's and movies. See also [Is their a difference between Rurouni Kenshin & Samurai X?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/34058/1458) on Anime.SE